# Open newly created record from quick create in ms crm 2013

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

How to open newly created record from quick create from in ms crm 2013.
Thanks,
Pavan N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the main navigation; once the record is created the save prompt allows you to open the record.

[image]

Image source [Magnetism Solutions](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/colinmaitland/2013/11/10/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-global-quick-create-and-quick-create-forms).

From an entity form, (when you add a record from a sub-grid), the record just appears in the sub-grid and you open the record from the sub-grid normally.