# Not able to get the record GUID in JavaScript code on save of Quick Create form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I'm facing a problem on the Save event of the Quick Create form for the Case entity. On Save event, I'm not able to get the record GUID in JavaScript code.
Our requirement is when the user clicks on Save button on Quick Create form of the Case, we would like to redirect the user to the newly created case record.

We have attached below Javascript function on save event of Quick Create form. This code works well on one of the 30-days trial instance, but it doesn't work well on the client development CRM instance.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var caseId = formContext.data.entity.getId();
    caseId = caseId.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");

    var entityFormOptions = {};
    entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "incident";
    entityFormOptions["entityId"] = caseId;

    Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions).then(
        function (success) {
          console.log(success);
        },
        function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: What's the version of CRM on client instance? And BTW, quick create form closes itself on save. So if it will close itself before a second then your script wouldn't run.

Comment: @KhadimAli I agree, I tried myself yesterday adding Js on save of quick create but context is lost in a while because quick create closes itself. I was using UCI.

Comment: what did you endup with?

Answer (score 0):

Quick create form purpose is flyout data entry without going away from current form/record. The same QC form is being opened from different places like Dashboard, Subgrid, Main navigation too bar, Lookup, etc. and allow user to continue the ongoing stuff. Out of all these places - only from the Main navigation, after the save - system will prompt with a toast to navigate to that record or option to create another record. [This is by design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32586139).

If you want to navigate to that record irrespective of the origin, you can try some scripts like yours but you are going to break the OOB pipeline flow. You may do some unsupported but it’s not recommended. I never tried it but you can add a function from `onSave` event, using `eventArgs.preventDefault` we can stop the OOB save, then open the Full Main form by prepopulating values from QC to Main form, then save it on form load.

Instead of all this pain, why not you open the Main form itself. :)